# script for tunnel setting in putty

Tags: powershell, shell, batch-file, putty

Currently our users are following below process to connet to redshiftdata warehouse cluster.

```
1. Open putty --> add jumphost
2. putty --> connection --> data ---> "Auto-login username"
3. putty --> connection --> SSH ---> Auth ---> allow agent forwading
4. putty --> connection --> tunnels ---> {provide source port,destination,add button}
5. After above setting open and then run 2 static commands
```

As users not tech savvy they dont want to use putty and do above configuration.
So i want to automate this using a script which should take username (step#2),inputs from step #4.
Users will run this script and create tunnel to warehouse.

Need some references or guidance to achieve this with batch script.

Answer (score 0):

You can install OpenSSH and use all its commands. There is also a Powershell SSH module which leverage .NET available via PSGallery:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-SSH